# How to trace executed guest function symbol names with their timestamp in gem5?

Tags: gem5

E.g. in AtomicSimpleCPU where each tick is 500 units, I would like to have something like:

```
0 function1
2000 function2
5000 function3
```

which indicates that `function1` started executing at time 0, `function2` at time 2000 and so on.

I could parse that out of `--debug-flags ExecAll`, but since that outputs large amounts of information, it significantly slows downs execution which is a annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a function for this on gem5 6bc2111c9674d0c8db22f6a6adcc00e49625aabd:

```
gem5.opt fs.py --param 'system.cpu[0].function_trace = True'
  --param 'system.cpu[0].function_trace_start = 0'
```

generates a file `ftrace.system.cpu` that contains output of format:

```
0: _start (6500)
6500: on_exit (2500)
9000: __register_exitproc (13500)
22500: _start (2000)
24500: main (4000)
```

where e.g. `_start` started executing at time `0` and it executed for 6500 units.

I tested an [arm64 Linux kernel v5.4.3. boot with it](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started) and it only slowed down execution by about 30%, which is great

The functionality is currently disabled for syscall emulation however:

```
BaseSimpleCPU::postExecute()
{
    if (FullSystem)
        traceFunctions(instAddr);
```

I tried to remove that quickly, and the output of `main` does seem correct, but for some reason the entry function called `__end__` seems to get printed every single timestamp before `main`, which is annoying. It should likely be easy to fix.

Comment: hi, i tried using this for SE mode, but it shows multiple main entries and does not show thread function in the trace.